# Issue while loading data from data reader to data table

Tags: c#-4.0, ado.net

When I am loading the data from data reader to data table than it skips the very first row.
For example,if I have 12 rows in data reader than in data table only 11 rows are coming.

```
dataReader dr=new DataReader();
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
if(dr.read)    
dt.load(dr);
```

Please help
Thanx in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

[`DataReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.datareader.read%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) advances the reader to the next row.

You don't need this check, otherwise use [`HasRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
dt.load(dr);
```

Note that you also could use  a `DataAdapter` to load the `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM T", con))
{
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: Tim,It works but If dr has no data than I think it will give the error

Comment: @Ankit: No, if there are no rows you get an empty `DataTable` with all columns (tested). From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e06d41f(v=vs.110).aspx): _"The schema operations take place for all imported result sets, even those containing no data."_

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, the Load method is passed a DataReader without a check for:

```
if (dr.Read())
```

So I would say that if you removed this line, then you will get all your results.  `Read()` will  advance the reader by one record.